# Invert photoshop pen pressure?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

This question has been already asked, but it's seven years old. Can it be done with now days photoshop? Or is there a workaround that involves photoshop?

I mean about the pen pressure curvature. When the harder you press the bigger the brush gets. Is there a way to inverse that in photoshop? Starting from a big brush with very low pressure to smaller and condensed brush size with higher pressure.

Comment: Sorry, but..... Huh? I have no idea what's being asked here. "Pen pressure" is a function of a *drawing tablet* and has little to do with any application in use. And what do you mean "inverse"? Can't one simply "inverse" the pressure used?? Rather than drawing - hard-soft-hard... just draw soft-hard-soft.

Comment: I mean about the pen pressure curvature. When the harder you press the bigger the brush gets. Is there a way to inverse that in photoshop? Starting from a big brush with very low pressure to smaller and condensed brush size with higher pressure.

Comment: Like someone suggests in this Adobe Forum post.

https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-ideas/p-inverting-pressure-input-custom-pressure-curves-for-painting/idi-p/12249543

Comment: I suppose I could see some use for it.. but it's still not possible as far as I'm aware. I still think you can do all this with your hand as one draws/paints and there's no need to have a curve for pressure. The point of pressure is to mimic real life... you can't change the curve if using paper and a pencil.. .you learn to control the pressure in your hand. I realize an argument could be made for "tech making things better" but I don't see that in this case.. tech for tech's sake isn't always an improvement.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What are you trying to do? What is the ultimate goal here? What problem are you trying to solve?  I don't think what your are describing would be useful.  I'm not aware of any drawing/painting application that would work that way, and even if it could, why would anyone want it to work that way? It's totally counter intuitive. I'm going to agree with @Scott here. Graphics tablets are designed for simulating traditional pens, pencils, and brushes. The harder you press, the thicker/broader/heavier the stroke.

Comment: It's for spray painting, which works the opposite way. The further away you are from the wall could translate to "less pressure", which when using sprays makes the area covered bigger. And when you take the spray closer to the wall, it makes the area painted smaller but way more condensed in paint. It's just for more accurate spray painting. I don't know if this principle applies to other painting methods though. Currently, as it is, it works the opposite way that sprays do.

Comment: Aren't you alluding to *Flow* and *Size* dynamics though, not pressure? To be honest, mixing multiple dynamics has always been a tad troublesome when a tablet has a limited amount of input options. I don't know about anyone else, but using things such as tilt or rotation to control a dynamic has always been a bit troublesome here.